# How to add objects to a list

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I add objects to a list? I have a list view and every time I create a new employee it seems like I am overwriting the previous one. What could be the most programmatically way of create and adding to the listview a new object? Thank you.
My code:

```
        private void btnCreateNewEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get values from cboBox anda datetimepickers (local variables)
        double salaryEmp = double.Parse(txtSalary.Text);
        int cellphone = int.Parse(txtCellphone.Text);
        DateTime hiring = dtHiring.Date.DateTime;
        DateTime birth = dtBirth.Date.DateTime;

        //List of new members object of class Employees
        List<Employees> employees = new List<Employees>();

        //Call the class and add a new member to the list Employee
        employees.Add(new Employees(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtAddress.Text, cboEmployeeType.Text, cboDepartment.Text, salaryEmp, cellphone, hiring, birth));

        //Populate listview with member objects
        lvwEmp.ItemsSource = employees;
    }
```

Here are images of the result 
[employee1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBn1V.png 
[employee2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udXQo.png

Comment: The problem here is every time you click the create new employee button you're creating a new `List<Employees>`, and only adding the newly created one. Disgarding any previously added objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are creating a new list and adding a new object to your list every time you click a button.

Use an `ObservableCollection<Employee>` instead of `List<Employee>` since you are using a UWP. This helps to notify the UI everytime you update the list by adding, deleting or editing.

Do something like this:

```
    //Declare your list outside the button click.
     ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    private void btnCreateNewEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Call the class and add a new member to the list Employee
        employees.Add(new Employees(txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text));

        //Populate listview with member objects
        lvwEmp.ItemsSource = employees;
    }
```

Please read more on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thank you very much, because ObservableCollection is something I was unaware of, and it makes everything easier and cleaner in my code.

Comment: Happy to help. You should also learn how to use MVVM with UWP instead of writing your code in the code behind. It makes your code cleaner, testable and helps with separation of concern.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your employees List object outside of the function and it will just works fine,I hope it will help.

Comment: @NicolasMartinezK, the answer looks solved your problem, pleas don't forget accept it.